# HTTP file upload without actually using a file

Tags: java, http, file-upload

I am using Apache HttpComponents' `HttpClient` to upload files to a third party web interface. Code looks like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("UPLOAD_URL");
FileBody bin = new FileBody(file, filename, "text/csv", "UTF-8");
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("Username", new StringBody("User"));
reqEntity.addPart("Password", new StringBody("Password"));
reqEntity.addPart("bin", bin);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

This is working as expected.

As this data is sensitive, I don't want it to be stored on the client side. (The program retrieves this data from a web service. I only created the file for the purpose of uploading it.)

So I'm looking for a way to not use a real file, but replace it was some kind of in-memory representation. I tried to use `InputStreamBody` instead, but those requests get denied by the third party system.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: So your application, as a client, gets a file from a webservice and uploads it to your server, acting like a proxy... and yet you don't want your app to have access to said file? I'd say you are asking the wrong question here, since it doesn't matter where you store it - in-memory or a file - the client *will* have access to it...

Comment: True, but this may still be a valid requirement - if you trust the user but don't want sensitive personal data lying around on disk.

Comment: Our web service is *not* returning a file, the file is created by the client application only for uploading it. The client application can access this data, but I don't want it to be stored as a file on the client machine. The data is deleted by the client right after uploading it, but there might be circumstances where this fails. In that case, the data will remain on the client machine for anybody to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem with using `InputStreamBody` is the `getContentLength` method, which looks like this:

```
public long getContentLength() {
    return -1;
}
```

This results in a *chunked* HTTP POST (`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`), which seems to be not understood by that particular web interface. So, I ended up extending `InputStreamBody` like this:

```
public class NoFileBody extends InputStreamBody {

  private final long length;

  public NoFileBody(final InputStream in, final String mimeType, final String filename, final long length) {
    super(in, mimeType, filename);
    this.length = length;
  }

  @Override
  public long getContentLength() {
    return length;
  }

}
```

Comment: can you show how you would use this with a `BufferedImage`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MultipartEntity: the addPart method takes a String and a ContentBody as parameters. ContentBody seems to be an easy interface to implement (FileBody implements it). You basically have to write the writeTo(OutputStream) method, to output your data to an OutputStream.

Comment: That`s why I tried `InputStreamBody`, without any luck. Will try a custom implementation now.

Comment: If I were you, I would base it on FileBody, which is less than 150 lines of code (including comments)! I have edited the post to show how

Comment: You cannot do that: `writeTo` is a method defined in interface `ContentBody`, so you can't just change its signature.